# negative margins with jquery created links

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="content-header">
<h1 id="title">Athletics Calendar</h1>
</div>
```

and the following jquery which adds in some links after the h1 tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body[class*=page-calendar-practices] #content-header h1#title").after("<div id='athletics_practice-schedule'><div id='inner-title'><a href='calendar/practices/games' class='athletics_links'>GAMES</a><a href='calendar/practices' class='athletics_links'>PRACTICES</a></div></div>");

});
```

The links show up, but since I needed to put a margin of -15px on the outer div which I was inserting (to shift up the div... I needed to do this for technical reasons), now if you hover over the link nothing shows, but if you hover right below it it does. Is there a way to fix this? I a different post someone suggested using the code below to modify the links, but its not working, nothing is changing color, so I'm not even sure if how to make use of that.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'body[class*=page-calendar-practices] #content-header div#inner-title', function() {
$(this).css('color','red !important');
}).on('mouseleave', 'body[class*=page-calendar-practices] #content-header div#inner-title', function() {
$(this).css('color','blue !important');
});
```

Comment: there is no need to use 100 selectors for selecting an element by id.

Comment: change this `red!important` to `red !important`

Comment: changed. but that didn't help things work.

Comment: The selectors in your jQuery don't match the elements in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to simply move a div 15px up, a better css should be position relative and top as -15px. It will calculate the static position and adds a correction of -15, for a simple explanation.Can you check if doing this still produce the hover problem.

Comment: I made that change and its still a problem.

Comment: I got around the problem by simply putting the the inserted code right after the div with id=content-header (for some reason I didnt think that would work before.) But thanks for your suggestion, css postion is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

the code changes the color of `#inner-title` div not `anchor` tags inside of it, try this:

```
$('#content-header').on('mouseenter', '#inner-title a', function() {
      $(this).css('color','red');                                
}).on('mouseleave', '#inner-title a', function() {
     $(this).css('color','blue');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FMv8w/)